# Would Deft Blade affect Virtuous Strike?

Tags: dnd-4e, rogue, paladin

I'd DMing a 4th Edition game, and one of my players is playing a Rogue/Paladin Hybrid and wants to take "Deft Blade" as his 11th level feat, but only if it would affect his Virtuous Strike.  Would it? I'm generally thinking no, but I'm still not sure about it.

> **Deft Blade**
>   When you make a basic attack using a light blade, you can target AC or Reflex.

> **Virtuous Strike**
>   At-Will ♦ Divine, Radiant, Weapon
>   Standard Action | Melee weapon
>   **Target:** One creature
>   **Attack:** Charisma vs. AC
>   **Hit:** 1[W] + Charisma modifier radiant damage, and you gain a +2 bonus to saving throws until the start of your next turn.
>   **Special:** This power can be used as a melee basic attack.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, because of the **Special** line: that power can be made as a melee basic attack.

Ordinarily there are only two kinds of basic attacks: melee and ranged. These are the attack powers you use when you want to attack but, for some reason, not use a class power.

But this power can count as a melee basic attack, so the feat applies.

Comment: Exactly. Alternately, it might have said, "This power can be used _in place of_ a basic attack," in which case it would *not* have benefited from Deft Blade.